# SQL QUERY ON JOINS

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables:

- **Doctor** contains docID , Fname , Lname
- **Patient** contains PatientId, Fname , Lname
- **Appointment** contains AppId , PatientId , DocId, AppTime, AppDate

How can I get Doctor Fname, Lname and Patients Fname, Lname where the AppTime is 8:30 and AppDate is 02/28/2018 (MM/DD/YYYY).

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: If `AppDate` is really stored `MM/DD/YYYY`, that a problem with schema design. It will be impossible to index that field properly, which cuts to the core of database performance.

Comment: Column AppDate data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should select what you need:

```
    select d.Fname, d.Lname, p.Fname, p.Lname
    from Doctor d
    inner join appointment A on A.docId = D.docId
    inner join Patient P on p.patientId = A.patientId        
    where A.AppTime = '8:30' and A.AppDate = '2018-02-28'
```

Format of date/time could be a little different. It depends on your database.

Comment: Yes, This Worked Thankyou soo much this was giving me a hard time . I want to upvote it but it is saying that I don't have enough Reputation

Comment: No problem. Just mark it as an "answer" on your question